# Manipulating the data from a powershell command in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, discord.js

I am using node.js to run a discord bot on a machine I have. I am trying to get the bot to read the uptime of a process (DCS.exe) and when asked, output the uptime to the channel or person requesting the information.

I have found the following powershell script:

new-timespan -start (get-process Dcs).starttime

and I can use the convertto-json to give me the following output:

```
{
    "Ticks":  1351592357572,
    "Days":  1,
    "Hours":  13,
    "Milliseconds":  235,
    "Minutes":  32,
    "Seconds":  39,
    "TotalDays":  1.564343006449074,
    "TotalHours":  37.544232154777774,
    "TotalMilliseconds":  135159235.7572,
    "TotalMinutes":  2252.6539292866669,
    "TotalSeconds":  135159.2357572
}
```

So, I am thinking I can write this to a file, and then read the json back in via that file when someone tells the bot to do this. But this seems like a messy way to do it, and is just creating unnecessary junk files.

Is there a way, in javascript, to call a child process to run the above command, and then bring the json data back into the bot so I can manipulate it. Once I have worked out how to run the powershell command and import the data generated I should be okay with getting the bot to send the data.

I'm new to coding in general, I have no background knowledge of what I should be doing here and I am very much a fish out of water. Even my copy/paste skills are not helping me get this done.

Comment: You can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/powershell

Comment: Okay, so, I've got that to output the result to the CLI.. how do I get that to output me a load of variables that I can reuse in my code later? I'm guessing I need to change the console.log to something else.. can I just use const and read it line for line?

Comment: Line by line won't work as it will all probably be put as one line in the file. You can find more about the child process [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)